# grails intellij ide 'run application' fails to load any controllers

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, groovy, run-app

any number of problems tonight.

I have a grails 3.3.8 app in intellij.  I have built some domain classes,  and in the ide I selected the domain classes and told it to generate the controllers, which it does.

if i right click the Application project in project browser (either to run debug) the app comes up but no controllers are loaded.  so i have to cease the session.

if i open gradle view and issue the bootRun command the app starts and the controllers get loaded!

however if i right click on the boot run action and select debug, if disappears off into the ether on a background thread and the IDE never fires and i dont get control of the debug session in the IDE.

This has got terribly frustrating and i've burn't alot of time tonight going round in circles

does anyone know why the right click on Application,  in project explorer, fails to load the controllers,  whilst bootRun does load them .

If i can fix **that** - then the debug from the project explorer should work.   Its very odd.

i had to try and recreate the project as this evening it got lost telling me my domain classes were no domain classes and when i tried to delete and controllers/services and rebuild them it kept telling me cmdb.$xxxServices gorm data services couldn't be found and refused to build hibernate datastore

you can find the project to look at [enter link description here](https://github.com/woodmawa/ticketAdapterUI) but it needs another project (ticketAdapter to run, and a library project softwoodUtils) i've used the json end points directly on my browser for the ticketAdapter (server) project and i know thats working - its not a grails app itself)

Comment: See http://jeffscreencasts.s3.amazonaws.com/woodman_run_app.mp4

Comment: "does anyone know why the right click on Application, in project explorer, fails to load the controllers, whilst bootRun does load them" - That is difficult to say without seeing your environment but I can say that in general right clicking on the Application works fine, as shown in the video I linked above.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are trying to launch a Run/Debug Configuration of a standard [Java  Application](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-application.html) with the `public static void main` method. For Grails 3 rather use [Grails Run/Debug Configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-grails.html) where specify the Grails module to load and grails command to run the app with:
[image]

Comment: The approach you described here works, but is not necessary and I don't think it speaks to why the situation described in the question doesn't work.  Grails 3 apps can be run from the IDE by way of the standard Java run config.  I do it routinely.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use gradle actions  like bootRun to run your app.id youdouble click a gradle actions from the gradle panel it will automatically  create and run a gradle run configuration. Then you can run or debug that configuration.